# Getting symbols for Windows XP SP1

Tags: windows-xp, reverse-engineering, heap-memory, debug-symbols

I know we're in 2020, however I'd like to study heap management and attacks that were prevalent at the time, especially in **Windows XP SP1**.

After installing Windows XP SP1 and windbg on it, I configured the symbols path as follow :

```
srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

Here's what I get from Windbg after the following commands

```
.sym noisy
.reload

SYMSRV:  c:\symbols\ntdll.pdb\3D6DE29B2\ntdll.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/ntdll.pdb/3D6DE29B2/ntdll.pdb not found
DBGHELP: C:\WINDOWS\System32\ntdll.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: ntdll.pdb - file not found
SYMSRV:  c:\symbols\ntdll.pdb\3D6DE29B2\ntdll.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/ntdll.pdb/3D6DE29B2/ntdll.pdb not found
DBGHELP: C:\WINDOWS\System32\ntdll.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: ntdll.pdb - file not found
```

If I try to access http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/ntdll.pdb/3D6DE29B2/ntdll.pdb from a web browser, the file indeed seems to not exist. My guess is that Microsoft doesn't provide the symbols for OS that are too old ?

In any case, anyone know how to get those symbol files, either from Microsoft or anywhere else ?

Edit : I also tried to download the symbol file for ntdll.dll with symcheck, but wasn't successful with it either

```
SYMCHK: ntdll.dll            FAILED  - ntdll.pdb mismatched or not found
```

Comment: Did you take a look at this page? http://joachimdezutter.com/windows-xp-symbol-files.html

Comment: Yes ! I did a little dance when I found this page and then found out that the links it provides seem to be dead :(